# Change QLabel text dynamically not working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

I am trying to change the QLabel text dymanically using QtDesigner, pyqt5.

Below is the code i am trying to use for changing the QLabel text dymanically.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:28pt;\">" + self.getTime() + "</span></p></body></html>"))

    def getTime(self):
        time = QTime.currentTime().toString()
        return time

    def data(self):
        time = QTime.currentTime().toString()
        print("Time: " + time)
        self.label.setText(time)
        return time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(ex.data)
    timer.start(1000) # 1 Second Refesh Rate

    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i tried to run the code in QtDesigner the output window open's for a second and closed automatically. Not sure what is causing the output window to close. Please advise me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you execute your code in the terminal/CMD since many IDEs do not handle the Qt errors, if you do it you would get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in data
    self.label.setText(time)
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'label
```

The error indicates that label does not exist, and that is correct because label is created after calling setupUi() but in your case "ex" does not call it. A possible solution is to first create the window and then start the timer:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(ui.data)
    timer.start(1000) # 1 Second Refesh Rate
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But a better solution is to follow the recommendations of PyQt<sup>(1)</sup> that states that you should not modify the class provided by Qt but use it as the widget interface:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(
            _translate(
                "MainWindow",
                '<html><head/><body><p><span style=" font-size:28pt;"></span></p></body></html>',
            )
        )


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.data)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.data()

    def data(self):
        time_str = QTime.currentTime().toString()
        self.label.setText(
            '<html><head/><body><p><span style=" font-size:28pt;">{}</span></p></body></html>'.format(
                time_str
            )
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

<sup>(1) [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you instatiate `Ui_MainWindow` twice: first as `ex` and later as `ui`. You connect the `timer.timeout` to `ex`, but call `setupUi` and `show` only for `ui`.

Try this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(ui.data)
    timer.start(1000) # 1 Second Refesh Rate

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score -1):

Qt Designer is only used for *designing* the UI, it does not allow running the program. Qt Creator can run programs, but only "real" Qt C++ programs.

You need to launch your .py scripts outside of Qt Designer, as if it were a normal Python script.